# Selecting elements by contains text in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of many divs. Each block always follows this pattern, several times on the page.

```
<div ...>
    <div ...>count</div>
    <div ...>Unread</div>
</div>
```

The goal is to check the sibling `div`, if the count is not zero, then modify css. Else skip.

They have no `id`s, and the class names change. Someone else wrote the html, so I can't improve that.

My code doesn't seem to select the div that contains 'Unread'. It should be modifying the color.

http://jsfiddle.net/ninmonkeys/5yDZb/

If selecting using `contains("Unread")` did work, I should be able to grab the sibling by using the parent?

```
$("div:contains('Unread')").css("background-color:red !important;");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css syntax was incorrect, but I don't think fixing that alone will get you what you want. The `:contains()` selector is matching parents of the divs you want. You could use `filter` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/TPeSP/

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'Unread' && $(this).siblings('div').text() != "0";  
}).css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: [I slightly modified it](http://jsfiddle.net/ninmonkeys/TPeSP/2/), this simplified my parent logic, since I ended up highlighting the parent div. -- I thought `$(this).parent()` would have selected the parent of the div containing the word "Unread". But I had to use two parents. ( I understand xml parsing in other languages, but I'm new to jQuery and javascript )

Answer (score 3):

Your issue isn't in selecting the elements, it is in your use of `css`:

http://jsfiddle.net/5yDZb/2/

```
.css("background-color", "red");
```

When setting the value, `.css` takes two parameters, the first is the property and the 2nd is the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div:contains('Unread')").css({"background-color":"red"});
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this from my phone and couldnt get the code formatting. :)